# Time Calculation And Duration

Tags: swift

```
func timeDuration() {
        let currentTimeStr = myTime()
        let oldTimeStr = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myTime")

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm:ss"

        let dateComponentFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        dateComponentFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
        dateComponentFormatter.unitsStyle = .short

        if let currentTime = dateFormatter.date(from: currentTimeStr),
            let oldTime = dateFormatter.date(from: oldTimeStr!),
            let durationStr = dateComponentFormatter.string(from: oldTime, to: currentTime)
        {
            print(durationStr) // 2 hrs
            lblDuration.stringValue = durationStr + " Ago"            }

    }
```

---

```
func myTime()  -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)



    return "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
}
```

I'm using both functions in my app, Basically my app keeps track of the last time I took a dose of medication. It also calls timeDuration function so I can display the amount of hours and minutes that it has been since last dose. It has a bug at 12AM it first shows time as 0.00.00 so some how it messes up the Duration. I provided a screen shot of this. Also I've tried adding an if statement to make if hour == 0 then change hour to 24 and it displays time as 24:00:00 but it still effects my duration code. Can anyone help.
[image]

[image]

You can download the source code of my project at link below.
[Source Code Of Project](https://www.leukemiafighter.org/Med%20Reminder.zip)

Comment: For `myTime()`, why don't you use the same `dateFormatter` as the other one?

Comment: Because I didn't write these codes, I just found them in examples and are using them to pice together my app, So I can learn how it works. I'm brand new to Swift only been learning for a week now.

Comment: I need to find a Good place to learn all the useful things. I mean I ordered a class on Udemy  but very little out there MacOs App Development.

Comment: @JohnMartin [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/macos) has some Mac OS tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You could store your times as `TimeInterval` which is stored as a `Double`:

```
    let timeOfDose = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    UserDefaults.standard.set(timeOfDose, forKey: "LastDose")
```

Implement a function to convert `TimeInterval` to `String`

```
    func stringFromTimeInterval(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> NSString {

        let timeIntervalInt = Int(timeInterval)

        let hours = (timeIntervalInt / 3600)
        let minutes = (timeIntervalInt / 60) % 60
        let seconds = timeIntervalInt % 60

        return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds)
    }
```

You could then implement using the following:

```
    //Get current date/time as TimeInterval (Double)
    let currentTimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    //Get date/time of last dose as TimeInterval (Double)
    let lastDoseTimeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "LastDose")

    //Get the difference
    let durationTimeInterval = currentTimeInterval - lastDoseTimeInterval

    //convert lastDoseTimeInterval to Date Object
    let lastDoseDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: lastDoseTimeInterval)

    //Initialise Date Formatter
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    //Create your output Strings
    let currentTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) //eg 19:40
    let lastDoseString = dateFormatter.string(from: lastDoseDate) //eg 19:32
    let durationString = stringFromTimeInterval(timeInterval: durationTimeInterval) //eg 00:07:47
```